# Communicating a custom view with its parent activity

Tags: android, android-custom-view

What is the best way of accessing the variables by a custom view from its parent activity? A custom view has been created by inflating from xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add getters and setters to the custom view class definition and then call those from the parent activity after it has been inflated.

EDIT: once a view has been inflated in XML you have no guarantees about what the parent Context will be. I still think your best bet is to add setters and then call them from the parent activity with the values you are interested in.

Alternatively you can use [`getContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) to retrieve the host Context, check that it is the correct class type, cast it to that type and then call methods on it to retrieve your values.

Comment: I don't want to access the variables of the custom view by the parent activity. I'm looking for the correct approach of how to access the variables in parent activity by the custom view that has been inflated from xml file by this activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking about getContext() however I wasn't sure if it's the best approach. As you said I don't know what is the parent Context. Since this layout is inflated from more than one activity, is there a way to check which activity is a parent at this particular time?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to code that way, but you can do `getContext().getClass().getName()` and compare that to the various class names you might expect. Once again, generally not a good idea to do that, but it would work.